# ASP.NET MVC - "Remember me" works only on localhost

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

we have testserver for a ASP.NET MVC project. Everything works fine on dev machines, but we can't login if *"Remember me"* checked in on the login page (in this case the request is redirected to the login page, no exception occurs as far I know).

If we open a browser in RDP on the testserver, it's **possible to use *"Remember me"* correctly as localhost - but remotely still fails.**

The two *web.config* are equals (except the *compilation debug* row).

Any idea?

Thanx in advance!

**Answer**

Servertime was wrong (minus 3 days) and cookie died too fast.

Comment: Please mark this question as answered.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days but thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pff...based on [this](http://forums.asp.net/p/1436341/3291097.aspx) article I found the answer quickly: the **server time is wrong** (it's a virtualized one and something happend) so cookie lifetime ends too fast.

I do not delete this question maybe can be helpfull for others.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...

You don't happen to have multiple servers on your testbed do you? Sounds like a classic [machinekey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9.aspx) problem if so.

*(aside - always compare machine.configs too in cases like this!)*

Comment: Thank you but I don't have machine.configs.